# Reference for molecular orbital theory

Tags: reference-request, notation

I am studying electron collision with molecules, and came across with notation like this $\left(\mathrm{B}^{1} \Sigma_{u}^{+}, \mathrm{c}^{3} \Pi_{u}, \mathrm{a}^{3} \Sigma_{g}^{+}, \mathrm{C}^{1} \Pi_{u}\right)$ for the $H_2$  molecules and I have no idea what they are.
Is there any textbook that explains what this symbols are?

Comment: The question has been answered on SE (the first two links), but also please refer to the Resources post (also linked): the books by Atkins and Levine will probably have more information. Consider also Hollas's *Modern Spectroscopy*, which is referenced in my answer to the second linked question. In a comment, porphyrin also suggests Herzberg's *Molecular Spectra and Molecular Structure* series.